# example folder always included during install of my package even when blacklisted in .npmignore and excluded in package.json files

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, npmignore

I created a react library and have my repo in gitlab and installed it using git+http://gitlab.com/[library-name]

I have an example folder to test my react components.
I want my example folder to be in my gitlab repository but I want to exclude it in my package files (tarball) during installation.

> This is my .gitignore

```
tmp/*
node_modules
.DS_Store
.sass-cache
update
*.log
.vscode/
```

> This is my .npmignore

```
tmp/*
node_modules
.DS_Store
.sass-cache
update
*.log
.vscode/
src
example
```

> This is my package.json

```
  "files": [
     "bin",
     "src",
     "public"
  ],
```

So as you can see I have listed the example folder in my .npmignore and and package.json listed all the directories I want to include in my tarball but upon installation I still have get the example folder present in the installation files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it registered in .npmignore, it will ignore it every time you install it, therefore, most likely, you will continue to see the folders of a previous version, try removing the package and installing it again.